# Add the word "readability" to the off topic close reason

Tags: feature-request, scope, close-reasons

Today we have this close reason:

> Code not implemented or not working as intended: Code Review is a community where programmers peer-review your working code to address issues such as security, maintainability, performance, and scalability. We require that the code be working correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge, before proceeding with a review.

I suggest that it gets changed to

> Code not implemented or not working as intended: Code Review is a community where programmers peer-review your working code to address issues such as security, maintainability, **readability**, performance, and scalability. We require that the code be working correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge, before proceeding with a review.

From what I have seen so far here, that is a very common thing to do, and it is also a very important thing to get feedback on.

Comment: Who will see this? What will it improve? Is there a problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Peilonrayz It's not a huge problem. It's just a minor improvement.

Comment: Process note: It's not technically possible to edit the custom close reason text. If anything, this would mean adding a new close reason with the new text and removing the old one.

Comment: @Vogel612 How would the difference influence the process?

Comment: One could claim that "readability" is already covered by "maintainability" as code that is hard to read can be tough to maintain.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm all maintainable code is readable but not all readable code is maintainable ;-] I think the suggestion of adding one more word to the list is a good one.

Comment: As far as I can tell, one of the things we should be commenting on is readability when we perform a review. Also keep in mind that a lot of the people that come here for reviews are beginners and don't know any better.